# mysql-connector-python cannot work with GBK string "赵孟頫"

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

Look at the code in python shell:

```
>>> s = u'赵孟頫'.encode('gbk')
>>> s
'\xd5\xd4\xc3\xcf\xee\\'
```

The last byte of '赵孟頫' is \x5c, the same as backslash. And it causes a sql error.

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''?????\\')' at line 4
```

Here is my code:

```
# db is mysql.connector object
sql = '''
    INSERT INTO scraped_products(
        site_prd_id,site_id,brand)
    VALUES(
        %(site_prd_id)s,%(site_id)s,%(brand)s)
    '''
dat = {
    'site_prd_id' : 'test',
    'site_id' : 1,

    'brand' : u'赵孟頫'.encode('gbk'),
}
self.db.ping(True, 3, 1)
self.db.cursor().execute(sql, dat)
```

Comment: More context/code would be helpful.

Comment: That would be a bug. Will you open one on http://bugs.mysql.com ?

Comment: OK, i will post the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution which would need some extra work to get it working. The following code example is converting the data into a [MySQL Hexadecimal Literal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/hexadecimal-literals.html) and sends it to MySQL without escaping, quoting or converting it. It's a bit a different way of executing queries, but I hope it will serve for now:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(database='test', user='root',
                              charset='gbk', use_unicode=False)
cur = cnx.cursor()

cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS gbktest")
table = (
    "CREATE TABLE gbktest ("
    "id INT AUTO_INCREMENT KEY, "
    "c1 VARCHAR(40)"
    ") CHARACTER SET 'gbk'"
)
cur.execute(table)

def gbk_to_hexstr(value):
    """Convert value to Hexadecimal Literal for MySQL
    """
    return "0x{0}".format(''.join(
        ["{0:x}".format(ord(c)) for c in value.encode('gbk')]))

# Convert your Unicode data using gbk_to_hexstr
data = {
    'c1' : gbk_to_hexstr(u'赵孟頫'),
}

# Use MySQLCursor.execute() _not_ passing data as second argument
cur.execute("INSERT INTO gbktest (c1) VALUES ({c1})".format(**data))
cur.execute("SELECT c1 FROM gbktest")

# Print the inserted data as Unicode
for row in cur:
    print(row[0].decode('gbk').encode('utf8'))
```